# How to switch command line tools on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra

I installed two commmand line tools on my mac.
So I want to switch command line tools.
How I can do it?

I tried switch from Xcode preferences > Locations > Command line tools.
However, `Command line tools beta 1 for Xcode 10` is not appear on this menu.

Xcode 9.4 is installed on my mac.
macOS 10.13.5

- Xcode 9.4 command line tools (bundled with Xcode9.4, it installed at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`)
- Command line tools beta1 for Xcode 10 (not bundled with Xcode, it installed at `/Library/Developer`)

Comment: The title of the cli tools is "Command line tools beta1 for Xcode 10" — so wouldn't that more or less indicate you need to use Xcode 10?

Comment: Stable version of Command line tools is able to install without xcode. (`xcode-select --install`) so I think command line tools is not require installing xcode.

Comment: Have you tried switching from the command line? See [this tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_SELECT_THE_DEFAULT_VERSION_OF_XCODE_TO_USE_FOR_MY_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_)

Comment: I think you should look to the answer here [How to switch between multiple Command Line Tools installations in Mac OS X (without installing XCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665704/5405601)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this command in terminal to switch xcode:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
```

> See: https://medium.com/@maximbilan/switch-command-line-tools-to-xcode-beta-2e99c54cb147

Answer (score 2):

call Xcode.app like this:

```sh
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

if you're downgrading from Xcode Beta version

Answer (score 2):

You can use .bash_profile to add alias to switch 2 versions:

```
alias Xcode13='sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode\ 13.app'
alias Xcode14='sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app'
```

Most important:
use `source ~/.bash_profile` to make the command effective.

Then, input Xcode14 to switch the Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ xcode-select -p

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer

Password:

$ xcode-select -p

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ xcode-select -version

xcode-select version 2339.

$ xcodebuild -version

Xcode 6.4
```

Build version 6E35b

Answer (score 0):

I have install 2 Xcode version 10, 11 and can switch them. But both of them have install on Applications. 
- Applications/Xcode.app
- Applications/Xcode 10/Xcode.app
May be you should move it to Applications inside  folder like me.

Answer (score 0):

**For normal versions**

Execute on the terminal the following code:

```
xcode-select --install
```

**For beta versions**

Once you have install your xcode-beta.
Install your `commands line tools` like usual, using the following code on your terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

One you have installed `commands line tools` is the step to download the new ones

To do this, open your browser and look for [apple developer resources download](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/)

[image: Screenshot from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/]

Select `view additional downloads`, you will need to logIn in order to continue.

Once you have logIn, look for the file you are interested in, in my case was `Additional Tools for Xcode 14 beta 5`

Select download and wait.

Once is downloaded if you try to open it, you will see the following content on the folder.

[image]

It is time to open `xcode`

Look for `xcode<preferences`

[image]

Search for `Locations`.
And on `command line tools` select the ones you just downloaded

[image]