# "'_Nonnull' cannot be applied to non-pointer type" while building FLTK on macOS?

Tags: macos, fltk

I tried to build FLTK 1.3.4-2 version on my mac. I followed the instruction, and successfully configure it.

But when I install it, it shows:

```
Compiling Fl_cocoa.mm...
In file included from Fl_cocoa.mm:55:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:128:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUUID.h:26:49: error: nullability specifier '_Nullable' cannot be applied to
      non-pointer type 'uuid_t' (aka 'unsigned char [16]')
- (instancetype)initWithUUIDBytes:(const uuid_t _Nullable)bytes;
                                                ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUUID.h:29:30: error: nullability specifier '_Nonnull' cannot be applied to
      non-pointer type 'uuid_t' (aka 'unsigned char [16]')
- (void)getUUIDBytes:(uuid_t _Nonnull)uuid;
                             ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [Fl_cocoa.o] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What compiler & version, or Xcode, are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.2.1. The Xcode is updated, which is 8.1.

Comment: You could have thrown this at a search engine and would have gotten the error explained probably. Anyhow, this is rather something to report as a bug. For a valid question here, you should have extracted a [mcve] from fltk first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you build system is a bit of mix'n'match and through that you have found a compiler bug.

The error message indicates that the compiler is not recognising that an array type (`uuid_t`) when used as a function/method parameter type becomes a pointer type (as C-style arrays are passed by reference not by value) *before* it checks the validity of `_Nullable`/`_Nonnull` – so it throws the error as `_Nullable`/`_Nonnull` are not applicable to array types.

However not only isn't this your code, it is system code which is causing the error, which is surprising. Which is where the mix'n'match comes in...

Prior to the macOS10.13 SDK the two methods causing the error, `initWithUUIDBytes:` and `getUUIDBytes:`, were not annotated with nullability attributes. By default Xcode 8.1 uses the macOS10.12 SDK and your code should compile with that arrangement – the included header, `NSUUID.h`, *will not* contain the nullability attributes.

If you wrote your own code with array typed parameters and specified nullability then Xcode 8.1's compiler would produce an error – the bug is in (at least) that compiler. But this isn't your code...

Xcode 9.4.1 (lastest 9) by default uses macOS10.13SDK and again your code would compiler – the included header *will* contain the nullability attributes and Xcode 9.4.1's compiler will not produce an error as the bug has been fixed.

So at best guess either you are using Xcode 8.1 but with the macOS10.13+ SDK intentionally installed, or you've managed to install the macOS10.13+ SDK headers and you are using a version of `gcc` which has the bug, or you've got multiple versions of Xcode installed and the command line tools are not for Xcode 8.1 ([How to switch between multiple Command Line Tools installations in Mac OS X (without installing XCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455245/how-to-switch-between-multiple-command-line-tools-installations-in-mac-os-x-wit) may help), or some other scenario where you've got mismatched compilers and installed SDKs – nobody else but you can know what is actually installed on your system; the header file path is a system location so the header causing the issue isn't a copy in the FLTK source folder.

HTH

*[BTW your `gcc` comes from 2007, if you are building with it you should probably update to something newer.]*